# No wifi on newly installed ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop. Everything works fine except that I cannot connect to a wireless connection. This is how it looks in front of me right now. I thought pictures would give more info. I really have no one to help me, so all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

http://sv.tinypic.com/r/6tlj0x/8
http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2dr9cgk/8

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I updated my software and installed broadcom wireless drivers. If anyone encounters this problem - follow this tutorial: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I did have this issue on an old mac book.

To solve it I connect to an Ethernet network my computer and run two time the update firmware, one time with the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And a second time with the software and update panel. Then you can open the additional driver panel and wait around 5 min time to find what is missing.

It did work fine for me. I hope it will help you.

P.S : I think it because the driver is not a GNU driver